# Python error: AttributeError: type object 'MyClass' has no attribute 'channel'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some help with my code. I have a trouble with getting the list of `self.channel` in player.py when I have input `import test`, but I am getting an error: AttributeError: type object 'MyClass' has no attribute 'channel' when I try to run the scripts.

The error are highlight on this line:

```
self.channel = test.MyClass.channel()
```

in test.py it show:

```
from player import MyPlayer

class MyClass(xbmcgui.WindowXML):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.channel = list()
```

in player.py:

```
import test

class MyPlayer(xbmcgui.WindowXML):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self.channel = test.MyClass.channel()
```

I want to get the `self.channel` from test.py to get the list of strings. Can you please show me how I could get the `self.channel` to get the list from test.py script?

Comment: There is a fundamental difference between a class and an object of this class. `MyClass` refers to the class but the `self` inside member functions refers to an object of it.

Comment: that is correct. So how I can get the `self.channel` from `test.py`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis from `channel()`. It is a field, not a function. Add parenthesis to `MyClass` so that the constructor is called.

```
self.channel = test.MyClass().channel
```

All the code put together:

test.py

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.channel = list()
```

player.py

```
import test

class MyPlayer:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.channel = test.MyClass().channel

    def test(self):
        return self.channel


print MyPlayer().test()
```

Comment: Thank you, but i am getting an error: `TypeError: function takes at least 2 arguments (0 given)`. There are two arguments in MyClass so what I can do to fix this issue?

Comment: @DanielEzekiel You shouldn't need to pass any arguments to the constructor as it's set up to take a variable amount of arguments, including none at all. I put the two classes in the same file and removed inheritance of `xbmcgui.WindowXML` for testing. I managed to successfully access and print `MyPlayer().channel`. Take a look at your indentation -  it looks messed up in your OP at least.

Comment: I am sorry but I need to use `xbmcgui.WindowXML` for skinning on the design for the dialog. I cant get pass of the arguments when I try to use `def test(self)   test_channel = MyPlayer().channel`. I still get the same argument like on the last time. Any idea?

Comment: For the sake of a minimal example to test, I removed the inheritance. Anyway, that is not how a function is defined. Not sure what you're trying to do. If you want to define a member function named `test` which returns `MyPlayer().channel`, use `def test(self): return MyPlayer().channel`.

Comment: still the same, any idea?

Comment: @DanielEzekiel I update my answer with all of your code. You can see it working [here](https://repl.it/LoPx/0) too, except it's all in one file.

Comment: Thank you, but I have found out that I need to use `self.parent.channel` in init(self) to get access to the list so I got it working! :)